# Reuse the function instead to writing new ones. Only change try block

Tags: javascript, node.js, function, ecmascript-6, try-catch

I am using axios to write functions. The outside of the function is always the same. I want to be able to resuse the outside of my function and always change the `try` and `catch` blocks. Is there a way to do that?

My code:

```
const funcOne = async (arg) => {
  const result = await axios(arg); //axios post
  try {
    //try code
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
  }
};

const funcTwo = async (arg1, arg2) => {
  const result = await axios(arg1);  //axios post
  try {
    //try code. arg2 used here
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
  }
};
```

I will have many more such functions. Is there a way to write this part of the code just once and reuse:

```
const func = async (arg1, arg2) => {
  const result = await axios(arg1);  //axios post
  catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
  }
};
```

Only my `try` block is always going to be different.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Introducing [higher-order functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/First-class_Function), you can return a function inside a function to kinda abstract it out:

```js
const higherOrderFunc = (fn) => {
  return async (arg1, ...args) => {
    const result = await axios(arg1);
    try {
      return fn(result, ...args);
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
    }
  };
};

const func = higherOrderFunc((result) => {
  //try code
});

const func = higherOrderFunc((result, arg2) => {
  // Try code. arg2 used here
});
```